# How to use my Asyntask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i m newcomer in android.

when i send request to server , to retrieve data, using soap api.

server give response bt take few seceonds, in duraton my screen background is black,

i m still using AsyncTask.(loader)

plz give any idea to remove.

Comment: we might need to see your AsyncTask and the way you start it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your processdialog  before starting/calling your Async task and in handler just dismiss it.

Comment: `AsyncTask` was made just to avoid using handlers, you should create and show the dialog in `onPreExecute()` and remove it in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think my [tutorial](http://knightswhocode.com/wordpress/2011/02/android-progress-bar-and-asynctask-tutorial/) should definately help you. If not, please be more spesific regarding the issue. Using progress Dialog is a good solution in this case.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en) is a good example of working with AsyncTask and Progress Dialog.